# Why doesn't to_excel in jupyter notebook not work?

Tags: python, excel, jupyter-notebook

[image]

I've been trying to follow a tutorial to export some values into excel. But the file formatting doesn't seem to come out right (The file that's in jupyter notebook has a file load error & there's no file on the rest of my computer). Here is the code I've tried to run.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'product_name': ['computer', 'printer', 'tablet', 'monitor'],
        'price': [1200, 150, 300, 450]
        }


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)

df.to_excel(r'C:\Users\ben\1.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: It looks like you're running jupyter on a unix system based on the mix of `/` and ```\```. What's going on here?

Comment: Your Excel conversion may have worked. However, you need to open the file it made on your own system like you usually open an Excel file to check. Jupyter doesn't handle Excel files. Your screen shot really cuts off a lot of information. Are you using Jupyter online? JupyterLite? I'm guess there was a file navigator pane on the left and you clicked on the Excel file, thinking you could open it? I mistakenly do it all the time, too. If this is a remote thing, right-click and download the Excel file to your machine. Then open it to check.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was a bit foolish and really didn't think to download the excel file to my computer before opening it!